# Creating a client for a existing web service out of a WSDL file with Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

I have a given WSDL file (a SOAP web service in the internet) and I want to use this service. For that I want to write a Java client, that sends the required datas (as XML) to the web service and the service itself sends an response.

Unfortunately, I am totaly new in web services. This is why I want you to ask for help.

I found a lot of ways to use SOAP in Java. One way is the AXIS2 framework from Apache, another way is the Eclipse Web Tools Project (WTP). I've tried both but couldn't get it run..

First of all.. What do I need to use such an SOAP web service?

I think:
- generate Java source out of the WSDL file
- write an client that uses this code
- with this client you can send datas to the web service (the client itself sends the data via XML) and the client can process the response

Am I right or do I have a fallacy?

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

> I think: - generate Java source out of the WSDL file - write an client that uses this code - with this client you can send datas to the web service (the client itself sends the data via XML) and the client can process the response

That is correct. You can use Axis2 as you mentioned, write a [JAX-WS client](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html), you can even write the SOAP message by hand (not that I would recommend that though).

You should try to get a successful call from [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html) first then write your client application. Use [wsimport](http://ayazroomy-java.blogspot.ro/2013/07/using-wsimport-tool-to-generate-client.html) to get a simple client working (if that's all you need a framework like Axis2 could be overkill).